# Spring Cloud Function Composition

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-function

I am trying spring cloud function with aws lambda.
Lets say, I have 5 different spring function (**A,B,C,D,E**) and function composition of like this **A|B|C|D|E.**

I specify which function to invoke using spring_cloud_function_definition in lambda,
so, **spring_cloud_function_definition = A|B|C|D|E**

Now, i want to route to other function (**lets say F**), **from function A** in certain scenario (lets say, on receive of some error code while executing in A) and **not move to next functions in function composition.**

**What i would like to know**:

1. **Is it possible to end execution in this function composition in middle based on certain parameters.?** If yes, How do i achieve.

   I tried **MessgaeRoutingCallback** but its not working for me. I created a class  that
   implements MessgaeRoutingCallback. I returned **"F"** in functiondefinition.  I tried to
   call this functiondefinition from function **"A"**.

On execution of composition,it goes like this **A -> functiondefinition (does not route to F) -> B ->C->D->E**

Answer (score 2):

Once again, (as it is explained [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/issues/795) and in the previous post here some time back) composed function is not a chain or flow or a pipeline of any kind. It is a single function created using `andThen` or `compose` methods of [Java Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html).
It is as if you wrote a single function yourself combining the functionality of all 5 functions. So the real question should be *"how do you stop execution of a single function in the middle of its execution?"*